Azure open AI sandbox playground - user uploads on chatbot front end
I have an azure open AI sandbox playground environment so I can create and deploy chatbots quickly. I can upload my own data so the end users can ask questions, but I would like the functionality for them to upload a document themselves, like you can in chatgbt interface, is this possible using this playground or copilot studio for example?
